# Running API calls from rundeck to Google cloud

Tags: rundeck

I am configuring rundeck to issue api calls to the google cloud compute api

I have tried both basic and oath 2.0 for authentication

Has anyone gotten this to work

Comment: Hi! Could you elaborate on your question? Maybe you need to define the google cloud CLI tool auth for rundeck user following this: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. [Configure](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth) the google cloud CLI tool for "rundeck" user, (home at `/var/lib/rundeck`) or:
2. Use [local sudo rundeck plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/sudo-local-execution) to call the command using the user profile which you have the google cloud CLI configured.

In the first option you can use command steps/script steps to call the Google Cloud CLI tool and in the second one using the [Local Command Workflow Step](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/sudo-local-execution#local-command-workflow-step) and the [Local Script Workflow Step](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/sudo-local-execution#local-script-workflow-step).